# Gremlin: Encountered unregistered class ID: 10

Tags: titan, gremlin

I am running gremlin with Titan-Cassandra as Back-end. Whenever I run g.v.map it gives me a weird error, any idea what is causing this problem.

Encountered unregistered class ID: 10
Serialization trace:

```
value (com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.TypeAttribute)
Display stack trace? [yN] y
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 10
Serialization trace:
value (com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.TypeAttribute)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:119)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:610)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:599)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:626)
```

Comment: What code caused this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and it was my serializer problem.If you are not using default serializer there might be an issue with null values.
try using readObjectOrNull and writeObjectOrNull instead of readObject or writeObject.
Also check if you have registered all the classes that your object uses using kryo.register(class).